# Shortcut to specific profile mate-terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-mate

As you can see, I have in the upper bar a shortcut to open mate terminal:

[image]

Here you can see the shortcut properties:

[image]

I have some profiles which I use frequently, and would like to have shortcuts for each one of them. I looked at the command help, but cannot find any parameter which indicates to open a specific profile terminal:

```
~ $ mate-terminal -h
Usage:
  mate-terminal [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                      Show help options
  --help-all                      Show all help options
  --help-terminal                 Show terminal options
  --help-window-options           Show per-window options
  --help-terminal-options         Show per-terminal options
  --help-gtk                      Show GTK+ Options
  --help-sm-client                Show session management options

Application Options:
  --disable-factory               Do not register with the activation nameserver, do not re-use an active terminal
  --load-config=FILE              Load a terminal configuration file
  --save-config=FILE              Save the terminal configuration to a file
  --display=DISPLAY               X display to use

MATE Terminal Emulator
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the man page for `mate-terminal` [online](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mate-terminal/), you should be able to read it with `man mate-terminal`, and it explains:

```
--profile=PROFILE-NAME
Use the given profile instead of the default profile
```

I'm guessing you would also see it in one of the help options you mention in our question. As the message you are quoting explains, you need to run e.g. `mate-terminal --help-all`  or one of the other options given to see the full help message.